# Unable to Preview state tab in AS 3.3.2

Tags: android, android-studio

I'm unable to view the state tab (see image below) in Android Studio 3.3.2. I don't find any setting to activate/deactivate it.

[image]

I added a file with this content in the res/drawable folder and res/color folder. Here the following result:

**res/color** : No Preview

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <item android:color="#FFF" android:state_enabled="false"/>
    <item android:color="#000"/>

</selector>
```

**res/drawable** : Preview display but state tab missing

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <item android:drawable="@drawable/ic_vision_off" android:state_enabled="false"/>
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/ic_vision_on"/>

</selector>
```